# session property does not persists across request in react express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am using the express-session module and have all the required setup below.

Session Middles ware

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);
```

The below API is called while submitting the login information

```
app.post('/registered-user/:email', (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const regUser = new User(email);
  regUser
    .findUser()
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        const error = new Error('No User Found!');
        error.statusCode = 404.
        throw error;
      }
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'User found...', user: user });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    });
});
```

---

As session data should persist across the request, when I try to get the session object logged, I don't see the added property `isLoggedIn` does not persist. Also.

NOTE:-
The post request is made from a React Component.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question is the session cookie getting set on your react app?

Comment: Hi, @NtshemboHlongwane Thanks for your reply. Yes, it's getting set in the react app. Is there a way the session value can persist in every request?

Comment: From my understanding on your reply if the cookie is getting set by your back-end to your client then the cookie should be persisted until the expiration data **unless** you have not implemented server side session correctly